# React Redux Issue: Modal Opens with Empty Data Instead of Existing Record for Editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I’m working on a React project with Redux for state management. I’m encountering an issue where, when I try to edit an existing record, the modal supposed to open with the filled data is opening with empty fields as if it’s a new record. Below are the details of the problem and what I have tried so far.

Problem:

When I click the “Edit” button to edit an existing record, the edit modal opens, but the fields are empty. I was expecting the modal to open with the data pre-filled from the selected record.

```
Relevant Code:

Here are the snippets from the AddLeadModalBody component and the editCurrentLead function.

AddLeadModalBody.js:

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import InputText from "../../../components/Input/InputText";
import ErrorText from "../../../components/Typography/ErrorText";
import { closeModal } from "../../../features/common/modalSlice";
import { updateLead } from "../leadSlice";

const INITIAL_LEAD_OBJ = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  cpf: "",
  rg: "",
  address: "",
  photoUrl: "",
  date: "",
};

function AddLeadModalBody() {
  const initialData = useSelector((state) => state.modal.initialData);
  console.log(initialData);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [leadObj, setLeadObj] = useState({ ...INITIAL_LEAD_OBJ });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialData) {
      setLeadObj(initialData);
    } else {
      setLeadObj({ ...INITIAL_LEAD_OBJ });
    }
  }, [initialData]);

  // ... [rest of the component code]

  return (
    // ... [JSX of the component]
  );
}

export default AddLeadModalBody;

Leads.js:

const editCurrentLead = (lead) => {
  console.log("Data to be sent to the modal:", lead);
  dispatch(
    openModal({
      title: "Edit Customer",
      bodyType: "LEAD_ADD_NEW",
      initialData: lead,
    }),
  );
};
```

Ensured that the data is being passed correctly to the editCurrentLead function, and the console log shows that the data is correct.    •   Inspected the initial state in the useEffect of AddLeadModalBody, but it seems initialData is undefined.  Console Output:  Data to be sent to the modal: {id: 8, name: 'Lindsay', surname: 'Ferguson', email: 'lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in', photoUrl: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg', ...} AddLeadModalBody.js:21 undefined AddLeadModalBody.js:21 undefined  I’m puzzled as to why initialData is undefined despite the data appearing to be correctly passed. Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are telling that `initialData` is undefined inside `AddLeadModalBody` component, it could be because of the following issues

1. The dispatched action `openModal` might not be properly setting your redux state
2. OR, you might not be importing the right state variable inside `AddLeadModalBody`

To debug this, use [Redux Devtools Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?pli=1) to visually see your redux state.

On a separate note (not related to the question), you dont have to use the `useEffect` here, since you can derive the required state without it.